# Async loading of javascript in Magento for PageSpeed

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, optimization, pagespeed

I'm trying to optimize my Magento 1.9.3 website, following Google PageSpeed hints, saying I have js and css that load synchrounously and block the page rendering.

To solve this issue, I'm putting all the javascript files with async loading, as advised in this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109878/make-merged-js-and-css-file-asynchronous-in-magento).

So all my loaded scripts looks like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.fancybox.2.1.5.min.js</name><params>defer</params></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.fancybox.2.1.5.min.js</name><params>async</params></action>
```

This way, running PageSpeed again, gives better results.

The problem is that I get plenty of javascript exceptions, because probably the scripts that are inside templates files (.phtml), load before the script has been loaded.  This is worse, if I clear the browser cache and reload the page. 
I've also tried an external module, [pagespeed](https://github.com/mediarox/pagespeed), but it also gives no better result on PageSpeed. 
I've read other questions [like this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139107/magento-2-move-the-javascript-to-the-end-of-the-body), for the best practices, but still don't get what is the best way to solve this "problem".

I mean, selecting which scripts should be loaded before the html, in order to make the 'above-the-fold' content to be working, seems crazy, but I also would not like to ignore PageSpeed Insights.

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Actually the extension I've installed works pretty well even though it is causing some problems with my css. 
Any chance to make things work WITHOUT any extension?