# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to speed up one of my latest website [www.spicytrendz.in](https://spicytrendz.in) using google speed test 
[speed test result](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fspicytrendz.in%2F&tab=desktop)

if you go to the above url you will see google suggestion to fix blocking JavaScript and CSS on page load.

I have tried quite a few things but failed. one of the link I found in this link 
[I solve Remove render-blocking JavaScript issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59318/pagespeed-eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-conte)

saying add prototype/prototype.jsasync in app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml

in my page.xml I can see the below entry:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head"> <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action> <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action> <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action> <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action> <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

</block>
```

I am not sure what the above code is doing. Can some one please tell me if there is any way I can call all my css and js on page load. Thank you for looking into this.

warm regards,
Saif

Comment: Agree, OP please edit if linked thread does not provide the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open file `page.xml` at location `app\design\frontend\default\{your_theme}\layout\` (I think your theme `pagayo-theme-002`)

After find code `<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>` in above file `page.xml`

**Reaplce code  from**

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

**to**

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>defer</params></action>  
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>async</params></action>
```

**Note :** Clear all cache in admin site

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks for taking time to answer. Can you please explain what "defer" and "async" does ? Yesterday I used just "async" againt all the .js and .css in page.xml and found out that checkout of product was't working. Does some .js need to be loaded before page load? Thanks for you time. If this work I can increase the page load time.

Comment: It doent work.... Any one has any Idea how can I load below two Js file Asynchronously?
bannerslider/jquery.flexslider.js
bannerslider/jquery-1.7.min.js

thanks